# ArrayList is initialized, but still returns NullPointerException when trying .add(string) method

Tags: java, android, arraylist, adapter

I am having this error when trying to use the add method to an ArrayList. I could see a lot of people where having the same problem, but they were not initializing the arraylist before add elements to it. But I am trying to add, and, still, I asked the console to return if the messages arraylist was null before the method, and it returns false.

```
public class ShowTalkActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> messages;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_talk);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String selected = intent.getStringExtra("selected");
        setTitle(selected);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messagesList);
        messages = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.message_list_row, R.id.messagesList, messages);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessage)).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println(messages==null);
        messages.add("Anything");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

System.out.println(messages==null); prints false. I also tried to initialize the messages ArrayList at the begining, instead of only declaring. Does anyone know what is going on? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is the logcat trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace from logcat

Comment: `System.out.println(messages==null); returns false.` ? What do you mean? `System.out.println(messages==null); prints false.` ?

Comment: copy your logcat output!

Comment: @greenapps, yep, that's what I meant, sorry. It prints false.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`. That is pretty obvious and has nothing to do with the code you showed.

Comment: Show getView() code please. You did not show enough of the logcat to see the code line which caused the exception. So no .java file of yours with line number.

Comment: @greenapps that's what is killing me. There is nothing in the logcat trace that points to any line of my code. Those were all red lines in logcat.

By the way. I don't have any getView() method. It will sound really newbie but, do I need a getView() to print a String in a ListView?

Comment: Well where is that TextView? Is it `R.id.messagesList`. You have no R.id.textview there?

Comment: I made this using ListView. When the user clicks on "send", it should add a line to the list and print the text there. 

The R.id.messagesList refeers to the listview, I have no R.id.textview. I have the layout for the row, which is the message_list_row, to be used in the listview

Do you need me to update the post to add the xml files for both the layouts the list's and the row's?

Comment: Yes please. `The R.id.messagesList refeers to the listview`. That looks not ok. The ArrayAdapter does not need such.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I was supposed to set the TextView as an argument to the adapter, and I was using the ListView itself. Thanks to you too =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainActivity.java

```js
package com.example.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 private ListView listView;
 ArrayList<String> messages;
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  setTitle("Setted title");

  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messagesList);
  messages = new ArrayList<String>();
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.message_list_row,
    R.id.messagesList, messages);

  listView.setAdapter(adapter);

  Button sendmessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessage);
  sendmessage.setOnClickListener(this);

 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
  System.out.println(messages == null);
  messages.add("Anything");
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
}
```

acitivity_main.xml

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messagesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="322dp" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

message_list_row.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messagesList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The above code produced [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK5Jw.jpg)

Comment: Great, man! It worked! The problem was: in the message_list_row.xml, I was setting the TextView with the wrong id I used in the layout. I was written messagesRow instead of messagesList.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** i was totally wrong. This sentence is wrong:
`You cannot set an adapter with an empty ArrayList, even if u initialized it before. The adapter will find no value and throw the exception.`
so my solution is useless. I will delete it in 2 days if it's useless. I did notice which was the problem later, but someone else already answered. :)
**EDIT END**

You cannot set an adapter with an empty ArrayList, even if u initialized it before. The adapter will find no value and throw the exception.

Try this:

```
public class ShowTalkActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> messages;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_talk);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String selected = intent.getStringExtra("selected");
    setTitle(selected);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messagesList);
    messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.message_list_row, R.id.messagesList, messages);
    //listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessage)).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //System.out.println(messages==null);
    messages.add("Anything");
    if (adapter == null) {
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.message_list_row, R.id.messagesList, messages);         
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else {
      adapter.addAll(messages);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Hope i understood your needings.

Comment: I tried what you said, but I got the same exact error. It made sense to me, but apparently its behavior points to the same result.

Comment: `You cannot set an adapter with an empty ArrayList, even if u initialized it before.`. I think you can. No problems with that.

Comment: I had his same problem and the solution i posted does work to me. I will study a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logcat it is pretty clear that when it refers to setting some TextView or other View object that a null object reference error is thrown, the error is almost certainly that the View object was not set up properly. That is where you must look when you get these errors.

Also a list does not have to contain content to be set to an Adapter. 
As you can see in my following code,
1) I create a new instance of "list_for_comm"

2) then i set it to the Adapter "adapter_comm"

3) then I proceed to fill the list with empty strings.

4) then if you want the list changes to actually be seen in the UI, notify the adapter with "notifyDataSetChanged"

5) put a smile on your face if there isn't one already.

```
public void initAllCommListStuff()
{
    lv_comm = (ListView_CommBar) findViewById(R.id.listView_with_comm_bar);
    lv_comm.setDivider(null);

    list_for_comm = new ArrayList<>(5);
    adapter_comm = new Adapter_CommBar(DisplayContactActivity.this, R.layout.comm_bar_layout_dc_portrait, list_for_comm);
    lv_comm.setAdapter(adapter_comm);

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        list_for_comm.add(new Adapter_GetSet_MovingBar(i, "", ""));
    }
    adapter_comm.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```